# Jquery.pwstrength password strength indicator rules not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to implement a password strength indicator into a project I am working on for the last few days and decided to use Jquery.pwstrength.

The UI works fine and two rules are working, namely `wordSequences` and `wordRepetitions`, however none of the other rules are being enforced but are all activated and have scores attached.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    options = {
        common: {
            minChar: 8,
            debug: true
        },
        ruleScores: {
            wordLength: -100,
            wordRepititions: -100,
            wordLowercase: 1,
            wordUppercase: 3,
            wordOneNumber: 3,
            wordThreeNumbers: 5,
            wordOneSpecialChar: 3,
            wordTwoSpecialChar: 5,
            wordUpperLowerCombo: 2,
            wordLetterNumberCombo: 2,
            wordLetterNumberCharCombo: 2
        },
        rules: {
            wordSequences: true,
            wordRepetitions: true,
            wordLength: true,
            wordLowercase: true,
            wordUppercase: true,
            wordOneNumber: true,
            wordThreeNumbers: true,
            wordOneSpecialChar: true,
            wordTwoSpecialChar: true,
            wordUpperLowerCombo: true,
            wordLetterNumberCombo: true,
            wordLetterNumberCharCombo: true
        },
        ui: {
            showPopover: true,
            showErrors: true,
            showProgressBar: true
        }
    };
    $('#password').pwstrength(options);
});
```

And this is the HTML page that I'm using the indicator on:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form:label path="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label required">Password:</form:label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <c:if test="${not empty passwordRequired}">
            <form:input id="password" path="password" class="form-control" type="password" required="true" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty passwordRequired}">
            <form:input id="password" path="password" class="form-control" type="password" />
        </c:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea as to what is going on here? I've included the correct files in the HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started using this so I don't know much about it, but I noticed that in your code rulescores is missing "wordSequences", also rulescores and rules differ in "wordRepititions" vs "wordRepetitions"

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact package it's hard to be sure (there's more than one package with Jquery.pwstrength in the name). It looks like you're using https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap/blob/master/OPTIONS.md or similar, in which case your `options` object is wrong, it needs an `activated` object to hold the `rules`.